# How to design a selectable list with Tailwind in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am working on a React project and I need to create a selectable list using Tailwind. The list should pop over in a combobox when the select option is clicked, similar to the image shown here:

[image]

However, I am not sure how to achieve this design using Tailwind. Can you provide guidance on how to implement this using Tailwind in my React project?

Comment: what you mean by  selectable list ? like in your design Select Banner Style and below are the grey boxes, which you can select one at a time ? or the dropdown ?

Comment: I need way to design select options, each row contine multi options,Like the image

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "each row contine multi options"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create using `input` type `radio`, keep the name same on `input` to be able select only one at a time, if you want multiple select then make that `checkbox`

something like this:

```
<h3 class="mb-5 text-lg font-medium text-gray-900">Select Banner Picture</h3>
<ul class="grid w-full gap-6 md:grid-cols-3">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="option1" value="" class="hidden peer" name="banner" />
    <label
      for="option1"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 bg-gray-600 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer peer-checked:border-blue-600"
    >
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="option2" value="" class="hidden peer" name="banner" />
    <label
      for="option2"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 bg-gray-600 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer peer-checked:border-blue-600"
    >
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="option3" value="" class="hidden peer" name="banner" />
    <label
      for="option3"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 bg-gray-600 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer peer-checked:border-blue-600"
    >
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="option4" value="" class="hidden peer" name="banner" />
    <label
      for="option4"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 bg-gray-600 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer peer-checked:border-blue-600"
    >
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="option5" value="" class="hidden peer" name="banner" />
    <label
      for="option5"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 bg-gray-600 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer peer-checked:border-blue-600"
    >
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="option6" value="" class="hidden peer" name="banner" />
    <label
      for="option6"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 bg-gray-600 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer peer-checked:border-blue-600"
    >
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="option7" value="" class="hidden peer" name="banner" />
    <label
      for="option7"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 bg-gray-600 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer peer-checked:border-blue-600"
    >
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="option8" value="" class="hidden peer" name="banner" />
    <label
      for="option8"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 bg-gray-600 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer peer-checked:border-blue-600"
    >
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="option9" value="" class="hidden peer" name="banner" />
    <label
      for="option9"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 bg-gray-600 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer peer-checked:border-blue-600"
    >
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="option10" value="" class="hidden peer" name="banner" />
    <label
      for="option10"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 bg-gray-600 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer peer-checked:border-blue-600"
    >
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="option11" value="" class="hidden peer" name="banner" />
    <label
      for="option11"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 bg-gray-600 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer peer-checked:border-blue-600"
    >
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="option12" value="" class="hidden peer" name="banner" />
    <label
      for="option12"
      class="inline-flex items-center justify-between w-full p-5 bg-gray-600 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-lg cursor-pointer peer-checked:border-blue-600"
    >
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MadanBhandari/3e021pho/6/).